# How do I access the public variables of a contract that is initialized in another contract in brownie test

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, brownie

Basically I have two contracts and one test file. Contract A is initialized in Contract B. Now I want to access the public variable of Contract A through the deployed Contract B in Brownie. The contract and test case are attached below:

**Contract A**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ContractA {
    uint256 internal constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000000;
    address public emergencyAdmin;

    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        address second
    ) {
       
        emergencyAdmin = tx.origin;
        _mint(second, INITIAL_SUPPLY ^ decimals());   
    }
}
```

**Contract B**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


import "../token/ContractA.sol";

contract ContractB{

    ContractA public A = new ContractA("Test Token", "TEST", address(this));
    uint256 public totalStakes;
    constructor() {}

    receive() external payable {
       
    }
}
```

**Test In Brownie**

```
import pytest
from brownie import accounts, ContractB

def test_tok():
    toke= ContractB({'from':accounts[0]})
    print(toke.A().emergencyAdmin())
    pass
```

As you can see I want to access the Contract A variable `emergencyAdmin` from the brownie test. Contract A is deployed inside Contract B, and Contract B is depolyed in the brownie test. Upon running the test, it is showing the following error message:

```
 AttributeError: 'EthAddress' object has no attribute 'emergencyAdmin'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create contract on wrong place.
If you want to create Contract A on contructor of B, you have to call

```
new ContractA("Test Token", "TEST", address(this));
```

Inside constructor. And then youll be able to store the ContractA variable on ContractB.